# how to release and auto-update electron desktop programs for linux windows macos without code-signing and semantic versioning?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater, github-release

electron-builder and its electron-updater dictate that program must have semver

- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/v23.0.3/packages/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts#L331
- electron's default autoUpdates does not support linux

electron-updater will only work on macOS if code is signed

- yet golang's .mod and clojure's deps.edn - clearly show that using source directly without intermidiary pa like npm or maven is a growing trend

question

- how to release electron program as files - what electron-builder calls dir and zip targets?
- how to auto-update by simply looking at github tags and downloading the new version of files and replacing them?
- does such file-based no-singing any-url solution already exist?

Answer (score 0):

- change heavy electron for light entirely jvm clojure .jar dekstop programs with swing ui
- one .jar for all operating systems by design
- lack of powerful web ui is not an issue - as programs do not need the most powerful ui - swing is plenty to connect user to data and to render on canvas